# Cannot start a child activity if the parent is not resumed

Tags: android, android-activity

when i start a activity: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.setClassName(context, "xxxx.MainFrameActivity");
 startActivity(intent);

---android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Activity could not be started for Intent { cmp=/.MainFrameActivity }
android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1970)
android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1617)
android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4472)
android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.void startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,int,android.os.Bundle)(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.void startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,int,android.os.Bundle)(FragmentActivity.java:67)
android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4430)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.void startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,int)(FragmentActivity.java:720)
android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4791)
android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4759)
```

Comment: ActivityStarter->startActivityMayWait:   \      ```(ActivityStackSupervisor.ActivityContainer)iContainer;
        synchronized (mService) {
            if (container != null && container.mParentActivity != null &&
                    container.mParentActivity.state != RESUMED) {
                // Cannot start a child activity if the parent is not resumed.
                return ActivityManager.START_CANCELED;
            }```

Comment: Why are you starting an activity like 'intent.setClassName(context, "xxxx.MainFrameActivity");' try to use 'intent.setClassName(context, "MainFrameActivity.class");'

Comment: i am sorry，"xxxx" is package name ,here is signal

Comment: Its OK! But use MainFrameActivity.class to navigate to the activity.

Comment: This problem arises in the crash collection process, and it is difficult for us to reproduce it in some unknown circumstances (only Sharp Android 8.0).

Comment: @zaven, did you solve the problem? 8.0.0, SHARP AQUOS C10 - same error in crashlytics log

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity_n.this, Activity_1.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```